# What is the difference between @Entity and @Document in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-annotations

Can you use both annotations on your database tables?

id, just like some clarification on there differences. thank you

Answer (score 4):

@Entity is used to map a class to a relational database, it represents a database table.

@Document is used to map a class to noSQL database (specifically mongoDB), it represents a MongoDB documents.

You can use both JPA or MongoRepository if you are using both databases by creating different entities and repositories for each database.

I recommend you to have a look at spring documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

Comment: can we use both the annotations together in a single model class to leverage table/document in a sql and nosql db at the same time? or have to create two different model classes with different annotations.

Comment: Yes, you can use a multi-tenancy approach where you can have a single class annotated with both Entity and Document but with different configurations for different databases. This approach would require a lot of manual work, and it's not recommended unless you have a very specific use case. I would just create different model classes ^^

Answer (score 3):

`@Document` is a Spring Data Mongo annotation while `@Entity` is part of Java Persistence API (JPA).

You can check both documentations:

- [Spring Data Mongo docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/)
- [JPA docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

Where into "Example 10. Repository definitions using domain classes with annotations" there is this piece of code:

```java
interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, Long> { … }

@Entity
class Person { … }

interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Long> { … }

@Document
class User { … }
```

And documentation says:

> `PersonRepository`  references `Person`, which is annotated with the JPA `@Entity` annotation, so this repository clearly belongs to Spring Data JPA. `UserRepository` references `User`, which is annotated with Spring Data MongoDB’s `@Document` annotation.

So you can see here the difference.

Comment: that makes more sense. so if I have a mongoDB database I use document instead of entity. thank you